# Replace javascript on a site with Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, string, replace, greasemonkey

does anyone know how to replace JavaScript on a site with Greasemonkey ie.

This is the default code:

```
var Test="1";
```

And i want to replace it like this on the page load:

```
var Test="2";
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you give a more detailed example of what you're trying to do? Because by the time a Greasemonkey script runs, any code that's part of the original page will have already run (unless the code is tied to a button press or some other event).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following in a userscript, assuming Test is a global variable:

```
unsafeWindow.Test="2";
```